# Notify-send messages from cron jobs in 22.04

Tags: cron, 22.04, notify-send

Trying to send notify-send messages from cron jobs. I've tried all the methods in the old questions and answers but nothing works. Maybe this has something to do with Wayland. Any current solutions for this?

Comment: "all the methods"? Like what? Does `strings $(type -p notify-send) | grep DISPLAY` say you need to supply `$DISPLAY` in the `cron` job? Is `notify-send` in the `$PATH` of the `cron` job?

Comment: What output do you get from the `cron` job? Check your local email.  Can you save STDERR and STDOUT?

Comment: @waltinator The strings command comes up blank. I'm using the absolute path to call notify-send, so I'm assuming it doesn't matter if it's in cron's $PATH. I've tried various iterations of passing DISPLAY, DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, XDG_RUNTIME_DIR parameters, but honestly I'm kind of a noob so I'm just copying and pasting. I haven't figured out how to see the STDERR and STDOUT yet, but I'll work on that.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523925/using-notify-send-with-cron) finally worked for me. I thought I tried setting the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, but mybe I had the wrong user ID since I was copying and pasting.